# Bash: "No such file or directory" error when performing string replacement on filename

Tags: bash, unix, imagemagick

I have a bunch of image files which contain the string "1170x603.jpg" at the end of the filename.  I want to run an imagemagick script which resizes them all and renames them to "FOO-thumb.jpg"

**Here is my code:**

```
find . -name "*1170x603.jpg"|while read fname; do
  $thumb="${fname/1170x603/thumb}"
  convert $fname -resize 45.6% $thumb
done
```

**This gives me the error**

> line 2: =./05/FOO-thumb.jpg: No such file or directory

For every image file I'm attempting to process.

Can anyone suggest how to fix this?

EDIT:  This error has nothing to do with imagemagick.  Even if I ommit the line "convert $fname -resize 45.6% $thumb"  the error still appears for every file I'm attempting to process.

Answer (score 0):

Know it's old- but had a similar brain fart that led me here.

shell variables don't use the $ during declaration

remove the $ sign from the $thumb declaration and it should work.

```
find . -name "*1170x603.jpg"|while read fname; do
  thumb="${fname/1170x603/thumb}"
  convert $fname -resize 45.6% $thumb
done
```